# TomEE disable TransactionManager defaultTransactionTimeout?

Tags: apache-tomee, transactionmanager

Is there a way to disable the timeout wihtout getting rid of the transaction manager in TomEE?

My sample transaction manager from tomee.xml is:

```
<TransactionManager id="MyTransactionManager" type="TransactionManager">
    adler32Checksum = true
    bufferSizeKb = 32
    checksumEnabled = true
    <!--defaultTransactionTimeout = 10 minutes-->
    defaultTransactionTimeout = 10000 minutes
    flushSleepTime = 50 Milliseconds
    logFileDir = txlog
    logFileExt = log
    logFileName = howl
    maxBlocksPerFile = -1
    maxBuffers = 0
    maxLogFiles = 2
    minBuffers = 4
    threadsWaitingForceThreshold = -1
    txRecovery = false
</TransactionManager>
```

But sometimes the transaction can be longer than 10000 minutes (~ 7 days).

TomEE version 1.7.4

Answer (score 0):

7 Days? Holy smokes! What on earth are you doing? :D

Unfortunately if you remove it, it will go back to the default. However, you could simply put the following which would work just fine:

```
<TransactionManager id="MyTransactionManager" type="TransactionManager">
...
        defaultTransactionTimeout = 10 days
...
</TransactionManager>
```

Comment: I could do that, but that would just increase the timeout. I want to get rid of it.

Comment: Timeouts are essentially for transactions, it's baked fairly deeply into the Java EE spec and into Apache TomEE. Your use case is definitely and edge one... I would set it to a very high threshold (10 days, 20 days, 50 days, 36612 days)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can wrap your code invocation with a bean setting the duration for that particular case using UserTransaction: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html#setTransactionTimeout(int)

Comment: That would require a code change, I was trying to port an application from WebLogic to TomEE with minimum code changes.